# 20.04 Cloud-init appears to disable ipv4 DHCP on eth0

Tags: raspberrypi, dhcp, cloud-init, ipv4

I'm doing a fresh install of 20.04 on some Raspberry Pi 3s.  The SD cards were flashed with Ubuntu 20.04 Server (32bit) using the RPi imager.

When cloud init finishes wlan0 has an ipv4 address from DHCP but eth0 does not.  Both interfaces have ipv6 addresses.

Setting the eth0 address with ***dhclient eth0 -v*** gives the interface the correct address, but that does not survive a reboot.

Despite what it says in /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml, adding the file /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg containing the line ***network: {config: disabled}*** fails to stop cloud init on subsequent reboots.

How do I configure the system to get a persistant ipv4 address from DHCP on boot?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this has nothing to do with cloud-init.
Even after completely purging cloud-init from the system I still only get an ipv4 address on wlan0, and none on eth0.